# How to log selected tcp packet

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I am troubleshooting a problem where a long TCP transaction (>=60s) would disconnect between my source (Point A) and destination (Point B), whilst passing through an internal Linux Gateway and several other CISCO routers/switches in between.

To investigate the issue further, I would need to enable TCP logging and facilitate my root cause analysis. However, I have very low disk space available and could not perform this logging for as long as I would like to. Therefore, I would like to know if there's a way to enable TCP logging for only selected TCP packets? I would need to enable logging at both the Gateway and the intermediate network devices in between.

Specifically, I am investigating whether Point A has received a FIN packet from Point B or from any other devices in between, which resulted in the abovementioned disconnect when a transaction takes more than 60s to complete.

Comment: i think this belongs to SuperUser. anyways i would suggest to read "man tcpdump"

Comment: tcpdump or wireshark, if you prefer GUI to command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

[tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) is your friend.  From the [pcap-filter man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man7/pcap-filter.7.html):

> To  select  the  start  and end packets (the SYN and FIN packets) of
>   each TCP conversation that involves a non-local host.
>
> tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn|tcp-fin) != 0 and not src and dst net localnet

So, `tcpdump -ieth0 filter_expression` should give you what you need.  You can add things like `and host a.b.c.d and port efg` to limit the capture even further.  You should be able to use that same filter expression with [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) if you prefer a GUI program.